# foreach loop Object is potentially undefined

Tags: typescript

Why does the ts compiler think that the Object may be undefined? I have a catch for that higher up in the loop. I have a link to the error in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Params%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ParamTypes%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ParamTypes%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20Date%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Params%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomething(params%3A%20Params)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20paramKeys%20%3D%20Object.keys(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20paramKeys.forEach(p%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20params%5Bp%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'undefined')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(Object.getPrototypeOf(params%5Bp%5D)%20%3D%3D%3D%20Object.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20doSomething(%3CParams%3Eparams%5Bp%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20params%5Bp%5D.toString()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D)

```
interface Params {
    [key: string]: ParamTypes
}

type ParamTypes = string | boolean | Date | number | Params | undefined

function doSomething(params: Params) {
    const paramKeys = Object.keys(params);
    paramKeys.forEach(p => {
        if (typeof params[p] === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(params[p]) === Object.prototype) {
            doSomething(<Params>params[p]);
        } else {
            return params[p].toString(); // Error: Object is potentially undefined
        }
    })
}
```

**Edit**

To see the error you have to turn on implicit null checking in the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's a known limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12636), the compiler does not record the result of `typeof` check for unrestricted indexed access. It looks like there  [was a PR to allow that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10565) but it was never merged - compilation slowdown was too much.

The workaround is to introduce intermediate variable:

```
interface Params {
    [key: string]: ParamTypes
}

type ParamTypes = string | boolean | Date | number | Params | undefined

function doSomething(params: Params) {
    const paramKeys = Object.keys(params);
    paramKeys.forEach(p => {
        const param = params[p];
        if (typeof param === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(param) === Object.prototype) {
            doSomething(<Params>param);
        } else {
            return param.toString(); // Error: Object is potentially undefined
        }
    })
}
```